# Neo4j docker container data is empty, when commited with existing data inside container

Tags: docker, neo4j

I was learning Neo4j and Docker. I wanted to create neo4j docker container and add some data to it using cypher query lang. And export it to another host. ***How can I do it?***

Steps I did

1. I run Neo4j docker image using `docker run --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 -e NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/Password0 neo4j:latest`. As I understand it pulls neo4j image, creates and runs new neo4j docker container.
2. Executed some cypher queries through neo4j-browser to add data to the neo4j container.
3. Then I executed `docker container commit NEO4J_CONTAINER_ID`. It creates new docker image from container.
4. Stopped all docker container process and run `docker run NEW_NEO4J_IMAGE`.

**And I checked data through browser, it is empty**

**I assumed neo4j docker containers save data inside container.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at below link

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes

> Changing the volume from within the Dockerfile: If any build steps change the data within the volume after it has been declared, those changes will be discarded.

Same happens when you run a container and try to commit the changes. If the changes made are to a volume then during the commit the data will be discarded.

The way for you to persist data in a image is load it at the startup/booting of the container. Or otherwise use external host volumes and then store the data there for persistence